# How do I force my app to stop everything until a single line of code has completed it's task

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, asynchronous

I'm using Kotlin and Android Studio

I need a list filtered out before I can do anything with it. However my code is running asynchronous and skipping over it and running functions that required the filter list but are just using the unfiltered version before it can be filtered.

Is there a function or bracket thingy that I can wrap the filtering function in to force the app to wait for it to finish?

I've tried feeding the list into the functions with the filter tagged onto the end and that worked, however (for some reason) it breaks my code later on which requires updating the list which then causes my recycler view to not update.

I just need a way to tell my code to stop, wait, then continue

Comment: Can you post some sample code and the problem, so it would be easier to provide help?

Comment: yeah there's lots of ways you can do this, but it really depends how you're running that code asynchronously in the first place. Also you should never block the main thread (if that's what you're talking about) because at best it will feel glitchy to the user - at worst you'll get Application Not Responding errors, and the user will get a popup asking if they want to kill the app because it's frozen